# Update Gitlab environment variables from a python script in a pipeline

Tags: python, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I am trying to update a Gitlab environment variable from a python scripts :

In the gitlab-ci.yml

```
gitlab_job:
  stage: gitlab_stage
  script:
    - python set_myvar.py
    - echo $MYVAR
```

In the set_myvar.py

```
import os
os.environ["MYVAR"] = my_value
```

I don't need the variable to persist. I just need it to be programmaticaly updated (from python).

So far, it doesnt do anything.

Comment: os.environ doesn't allow you to modify your shell's environment variables, it's simply a dictionary representation of them. You'd be much better off setting the environment variable in bash, and using the python to create an output for it. Something like `export MYVAR=$(python -c 'print("NewValue")')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. The UNIX process model requires certain attributes to be private to a process. This includes such things as the current working directory of the process **and its environment variables**. Each of these private attributes is inherited; either implicitly or explicitly depending on how the child process is spawned by its parent process. A child process cannot modify those private attributes of its parent.

There are ways to workaround the aforementioned limitation. For example, the child process could write the new `var=value` pairs to stdout. The parent process that runs your python program can then read those strings and add them to its environment. In your case your python program would do `print("MYVAR=my_value")` and you would run it from your gitlab script as `eval $(python set_myvar.py)`.